# Generic Video driver for Windows 7 to replace VgaSave?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, graphics-card, display-driver

My laptop currently has some hardware problems (which I believe is a failing VRAM chip) that prevent its GPU from running at its full capacity. I am planning to fix it, but for now I am stuck with the VgaSave driver, which, I believe, is running on the same GPU, but uses only a limited amount of VRAM.

With VgaSave the laptop is stable and works fine, except that it became slower, the maximum screen resolution is only 1024x768 and there is no "Sleep mode" in Windows OS, which means that I have to close all programs and shutdown the laptop every time I take a break.

I wonder if there is a generic video driver for Windows 7 that I can download and use instead of the VgaSave driver, to at least have a normal screen resolution and the "Sleep mode". I do not need it do support DirectX or anything fancy. Just the very basic stuff.

It would ease my life substantially, until I am able to fix the GPU.

Thank you.

---

UPDATE:
My laptop is Dell Inspiron N5010 with Intel Core i5 M480 processor and ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 GPU.

Comment: Are you sure you mean IGP rather than a dedicated card? An IGP would share your system memory and if its memory is faulty then you have a faulty dimm. It would also would be impossible to replace without replacing your processor. The "I" in IGP would be"integrated" meaning it is built in to your processor rather than being a separate part with its own memory. It might be worth actually listing your CPU and graphics card to be clear.

Comment: Hi, Mokubai, you are right, I made a mistake. It should be correct now.